# How to get proper string from Guava range class

Tags: java, guava, rangeset

For example i do the following:

```
RangeSet<Long> rangeSet = TreeRangeSet.create();;
rangeSet.add(Range.closed(20L,29L).canonical(DiscreteDomain.longs())); 
rangeSet.add(Range.closed(10L,19L).canonical(DiscreteDomain.longs()));
rangeSet.add(Range.closed(50L,59L).canonical(DiscreteDomain.longs()));
System.out.println(rangeSet);
```

I get the following output:

`[[0‥30), [50‥60)]`

As I see 30 is not in range because it is closedOpen and 60 is not in range because it is also closedOpen.

How to get from the Range class the following strings?

```
[0‥30) contains numbers from 0 to 29
[50‥60) contains numbers from 50 to 59
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ContiguousSet<Long> set =
    ContiguousSet.create(range, DiscreteDomain.longs());
```

Then you can use

```
set.first()
```

and

```
set.last()
```

to get the values you want.

Comment: That you very much!

Comment: FYI: You do not need to convert the `ContiguousSet` into a `Range`. `ContiguousSet` has methods `first()` and `last()`.

Comment: @mfulton26 indeed - missed that!